# WSL2 install via Packer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, packer

I doing a golden Image using Packer and azure devops,

```
     provisioner "powershell" {
elevated_user = "SYSTEM"
elevated_password = ""
inline = ["wsl --install"]
```

}

Once the code runs i get

```
 azure-arm.windowsvm: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: Virtual Machine Platform has been installed.
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
    azure-arm.windowsvm: 
==> azure-arm.windowsvm: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
==> azure-arm.windowsvm: 
==> azure-arm.windowsvm: Deleting individual resources ...
```

how can i check whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without full Packer file. Two reasons are possible when you see this error:

1. [Missing admin permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#prerequisites:%7E:text=Open%20PowerShell%20or%20Windows%20Command%20Prompt%20in%20administrator%20mode%20by%20right%2Dclicking%20and%20selecting%20%22Run%20as%20administrator%22) - this probably doesn't apply to your case
2. [OS does not meet the requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#prerequisites) - Windows 10 version 2004 and higher (Build 19041 and higher) or Windows 11
3. [Required features are not installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) - for older Windows you have to check manual installation procedure. Two Windows features needs to be installed first: Windows Subsystem for Linux and Virtual Machine Platform

The same problem is described here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9521